# Adobe Javascript in Action Wizard vs a form button

Tags: javascript, pdf, stream

I've been writing some javascript to fill in fields of a PDF form.  I initially wrote the code in the "Action Wizard" in Adobe.  I did not realize at the time that I was adding it to my local application, not the form itself.  So I then copied it to a button on the from and now it is not working.

The code:

```
/* Test to read in a file and update the fields*/
var dataFrom = null;
//Grab the current path and update it to indicate the TempInfo location
var strPath = this.path;
strPath = strPath.slice(0,-12);
strPath = strPath + "TempInfo.txt"

//Get data from TempFile into array, display message if no file found
try{
  var dataStream = util.readFileIntoStream(strPath);
  var dataFrom = util.stringFromStream(dataStream);
}catch(e){
app.alert("Temp file not found");
}

//Put the data into an array and update the fields
var strTest = new Array();
strTest = dataFrom.split(/\n/);

getField("Username").value = strTest[0];
getField("UID").value = strTest[1];

//Clear the data
dataStream = null;
dataFrom = null;
strTest = null;
```

I am getting the app.alert "Temp file not found" so the "var dataStream = readFileInfoStream(strPath);" isn't reading in the file.  I did app.alerts to verify the strPath variable has the right path and one to verify that dataStream is coming up null.  Being that I copied it from the Action Wizard, I am unsure why its not working.

Just to make this a little odder (at least to me), if I open the JavaScript editor and highlight the code, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the util.readFileIntoStream method, when the cDIPath parameter is specified, the method can only be executed in a privileged context meaning during a batch, console event, or Action. It won't work when executed within the document context unless you create a Trusted Function.

Read this to understand how to executing privileged methods in a non-privileged context...
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_Dev_Contexts%2FExecuting_privileged_methods_in_a_non-privileged_context.htm&rhsearch=trusted%20function&rhsyns=%20

Comment: This looks like it would be useful, but I ran into problems there as well.  In the JavaScript console, I ran: 'app.getPath("user", "javascript");' and got back "undefine", did the same for 'app' and it came back with a result, but I dont have privileges to that folder.  Is there a way I can define the user folder?

Comment: If you need to distribute this code to others, you're better off doing it as an Action or Custom Command. If you set it up as a Trusted Function, users would need to install that as well. But, in response, I'm guessing you are on Windows. See this article for instructions... https://www.pdfscripting.com/public/Installing_Automation_Tools.cfm

Comment: Really appreciate the info and links.  I'll take a look at the instructions for the folder level scripts and look up what custom commands are and go with what will work best.